# get the door for her so she doesn't scrape in on the curb? what does it mean?

Tags: expressions, context

the expression comes from the link below
https://www.pinterest.co.kr/pin/391742867559861412/

'get the door for her so she doesn't scrape in on the curb'? what does it mean?

get the door, I get that picture says it all but 'so she doesn't scrape in on the curb'? what does it mean? scrape is like to rip, to rob of something. and "on the curb"? I by no mean can't translate this expression nor I can get the catch of the meme... help?

Comment: Is that a Korean website? (co.kr).

Comment: Well, it sounds to me like a car door, which if swung wide open, will scrape the curb--its bottom edge will be just a bit higher than the curb.  If someone opens the door for her so she can just get out, that's "getting the door for her."

Comment: "in" was probably a typo for "it".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the OP's misspelling. Replacing "in" with "it" the meaning of the meme is instantly clearer. The question also lacks research... the meaning of "curb" can be found in any online dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong on this but it sounds like to hold the door if you are in front of a lady so she doesn't scrape or squeeze through the door as it shuts behind you. Almost like someone made a saying out of the gentlemen code.

Or if you are referencing the picture that states "Get the door for her so she doesn't scrape **IT** on the curb", it could be literal in that you should open the car door for a lady else she might scrape it. This implies that she might not be as concerned as you for the safety of the car. And it's humor comes from the fact you aren't opening the door to be polite, but to protect your car.

Comment: oh my god. thank you guys. the problem came from me not knowing what curb means ....  thank you guys. it's been my real head scratcher